# What's the best way to test for a preexisting record in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My MVC project uses entity framework to handle communication with the database.

The web application needs the ability to verify that a value provided by the user via a web form does not exist in the database before the SaveChanges method is invoked. An index on the database table prevents duplicate values. I don't want to rely on the SQL exception for finding out there's a problem with the new value.

What I did was to use a Linq statement that retrieves any records that have a ContactKey property with the submitted value. Then I use the Count property of the entity. If it returns 0, then I assume that the new value is unique. Here's the code snippet:

```
// newKey is the value provided by user
var existing = from c in db.Contacts where c.ContactKey == newKey select c;
if (existing.Count()==0)
{
    isUnique = true;
}
```

While this seems to work as intended, I'm new to Linq and am not sure if this is the best way to go.

I would appreciate any confirmation or suggestions for improvement.

Don Langham

Comment: Keep in mind that you're querying the database, then coming back to your code before inserting, which means it's possible (unlikely though) that between the time you check and the time you insert, that value may be inserted by a different web user. If this is a concern, you may want to consider wrapping up the select and insert inside a transaction, possibly in a traditional stored proc.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is something I should account for. I don't know how to make the Model.SaveChanges call a stored procedure (perhaps a class that inherits from whatever base class handles that?).

Comment: If it's Database-first with EF5, all the work is done for you - when you build your model, it lets you import procs directly, and you can call `db.MyStoredProcName(someParam, nextParam)`, and it builds the return types and everything for you. With EF4 it's just a little more work, building a Function Import (still in the designer though) to match the proc. With code-first, I don't think it's built-in, so you'd have to execute the proc the old-fashioned way and map the parameters and return values by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

```
bool ifExist = db.Contacts.Any(r=> r.ContactKey == newKey);
```

Comment: boo - is that a new datatype ;)

Comment: use var or you don't like it?

Comment: @speti43 in StackOverflow answers it's more helpful to specify `bool` just to make it clear what the code is returning. Yes, the code would work with `var`, but specifying your types makes it easier for the reader to understand, and the aim of StackOverflow is to educate, not to just produce code that works.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: ok, I understand, but the new tendency is to use implicit declaration, which can helps a lot with anonymous types also and make the code more simle. So you can also educate of "var" usage. I understand your arguments too.